# Debian 8 resolv.conf overwritten by IPv6 autoconfiguration/DHCP when DHCP disabled

Tags: debian, dhcp, ipv6, debian-jessie, dhcpv6

I have recently installed Debian 8 on a network with IPv6 DHCP Enabled. /etc/resolv.conf is being overwritten by the IPv6 DHCP entires continually despite the fact that all IPv6 DHCP is disabled, autoconfiguration of IPv6 is disabled, and no dhclient process exists. If I modify the IPv6 DHCP DNS servers on the router, they are updated in short order in /etc/resolv.conf. The following are true:

- resolvconf is not on the system
- networkmanager is not on the system
- autoconfiguration of IPv6 has been forcefully disabled by `net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0` and `net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0` AND `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=0` because for some reason the first two were insufficient.
- No dhclient process is active
- Auditd returns the PID of some shell that instantly dies when looking for edits to resolv.conf. May need to step up my stack trace game.
- `dns-nameserver` entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` are entirely ignored for both ipv4 and v6

I would prefer an answer that isn't "disable IPv6 entirely" though I'm getting close to that point (and suffice it to say that were this a physical machine and not a virtual one I would have thrown it out the window already).

EDIT: Note that net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 in sysctl fixes this issue, but it would appear that resolv.conf now gets entirely cleared periodically, breaking DNS.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xx.xx.xx.xx
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway xx.xx.xxx.xx
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

#auto 6to4
#iface 6to4 inet6 6to4
#       local xx.xx.xxx.xx
#       dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the `rdnssd` package installed? That runs a daemon which spawns shell scripts that certainly behave in the way you've described above.

Note that the `dns-nameservers` attribute on the interface only works with `resolvconf`.

Answer (score 1):

You could monitor things to see what process is modifying the file

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file

If desired, temporarily you can edit resolv.conf and then

> chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf

To prevent anything from modifying it

Comment: I did end up setting the immutable bit on /etc/resolv.conf. I think this is a legitimate bug with Debian's handling of IPv6 so I'm going to pursue that avenue.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to solve this "issue" is installing **resolvconf** package.

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

After that, */etc/resolv.conf* is replaced by a symbolic link to */etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf* that is dynamically generated by **resolvconf** with the info from the file */etc/network/interfaces*

**Note that *dns-nameserver* entries in */etc/network/interfaces* are ignored if you don't have resolvconf package installed in your system**. You can find more info about the [**resolvconf** package info in Debian wiki documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#The_resolv.conf_configuration_file) or using man pages.

```
man resolvconf
```